# Custom property descriptor in .net

Tags: c#, wpf, icustomtypedescriptor

I am using the [PropertyGrid](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid) from extended wpf tool kit.

There is a requirement to implement localization for property grid.
To achieve this , a base class implements `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and another class that implements `PropertyDescriptor`.

I am able to localize property grid. But there is a problem associated.

1) If a base class implements `ICustomTypeDescriptor` , and suppose if derived class has a property name(an overridden property) same as of base class,
an exception is thrown.

### BaseClass :

```
    [Category("Font")]
    [DisplayName("PROPGRID_FONTALIGN")]
    public virtual TextAlignment FontAlign
    {
        get
        {
            if (CrControl.FontAlign == "Left")
                return TextAlignment.Left;
            if (CrControl.FontAlign == "Right")
                return TextAlignment.Right;
            if (CrControl.FontAlign == "Center")
                return TextAlignment.Center;
            return TextAlignment.Justify;
        }
        set
        {
            CrControl.FontAlign = value.ToString();
            SetProperty(ref _fontAlign, value);
        }
    }
```

### Derived Class:

```
    [Browsable(false)]
    public override TextAlignment FontAlign
    {
        get { return base.FontAlign; }
        set { base.FontAlign = value; }
    }
```

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: It is System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException and the message says "object does not match target type"

Comment: **Where** is this exception thrown?

Comment: Exception is thrown in class "CustomPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor"
at following method

        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            return Root.GetValue(component);
        }